# How to display data of MYSQL in java with using of AJAX

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have one table in mysql which has three field with data inserted. there are three fields in it which are as below.
[image: this is snapshot of a database, table and inserted field in it]

i want to display this data on a web browser with using ajax in java.

i search on a net and find this below code are most useful

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ajax_demo","root","");  
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from ajax");
```

what are other things i have to implement for displaying output.

Comment: Naming your table ajax is just going to confuse you.  Ajax is just a javascript technology to send a HTTP request to a page on your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a AJAX request, the main code body for an ajax request is the following

```
request.onreadystatechange=handleResponse;
request.open(typeReq, url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
request.send(queryString);
```

typeReq is the type of the request: POST or GET.
url: the destination url address.
queryString: the set of data which you want to send.

handleResponse is a function to hanled the response. For example:

```
function handleResponse () {
if (request.readyState = 4) {
if (request.status = 200) {
var response = request.responseText;
//code to handle response
} else {
//code to handle errors
}
}
```

Now, you can use an API like prototype or jquery, it's easier.

I hope this information helps you.

Good Luck